# Script executed by a systemd service not deleting the service file

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to create a `systemd` service that executes a shell script on reboot, this script will delete some files, delete the service and then delete itself. But when I enable the service, it runs the script, the files get deleted, but it fails on deletion of the service. My script is:

```
rm /var/local/myvars/file
systemctl stop myservice.service
systemctl disable myservice.service
rm /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
rm /var/tmp/myscript
```

myservice.service is:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run script on Reboot
Before = 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/var/tmp/myscript
RemainAfterExit=no
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I doing wrong? What I want to do is delete certain file after reboot, hence I want a way to run some script only once after reboot. Is this the correct way to do it or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following service and script worked for me.
Service:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run script on Reboot
Before = 
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/tmp/myscript
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script:

```
rm -rf files
systemctl disable myservice.service
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
rm -f /var/tmp/myscript
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to make it as a service. Instead you can create a cron job to execute the script on each reboot.

you can do

```
sudo crontab -e #to open it as root
```

then in that add a line below like:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /path_to_your_script.
```

then save and close the file and type

```
systemctl restart cron
```

Comment: I thought of cronjob, but I also want to make another service wait on this service. in systemd I can do this with the Before argument in [Unit] but no such thing in cronjob

Comment: Well I can guide you for some desi jugaad methods. Like you can create a xyz file on execution of cronjob. 
and on service you can mention that service should not run before the xyz file is created.